# How to approach XML elements with same names (inside 1 XML doc) without prefixes?

Tags: xml, xsd

Can I mix html `table` and data `table` in one XML without resort to prefixes defined on `root`?

```
<root xmlns="kuku"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="kuku test.xsd">

    <table xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <tr>
            <td>Microsoft</td>
            <td>Apple</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table xmlns="http://www.overstock.com/furniture">
        <name>Drawing board</name>
        <length>600</length>
        <width>250</width>
    </table>
</root>
```

There should be 2 schemes, one for the 1st table and other for the second, what should I write in the `test.xsd`, taking into account that there are no other things inside the `root` except two tables? Maybe I can leave XSD empty.

Comment: Of course you can; who can stop you?  Or, to put the same point more seriously:  you have left out of the question any information about what properties you want the XML to have and/or what software you want it to work with.  Are you trying to make the data be conforming XML?  Be valid against a particular XSD schema? Valid against *some* XSD schema?  Work with some software that requires an XSD schema?  Work with some software that requires validity against an XSD schema?  We cannot tell you how to achieve your goals if we don't know what they are.

Comment: just use two different names for namespaces you are referencing

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if your goal is to make the document schema-valid against the schema described by `test.xsd`, and that you control that document, so it can contain anything you like.  If so, then you probably want test.xsd to contain

- an import of a schema for namespace http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml, or at least for the table vocabulary
- an import for namespace http://www.overstock.com/furniture
- a declaration of element {kuku}root that says it can validly contain a {http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}table element followed by a {http://www.overstock.com/furniture}table element